# Magetno2 custom subtotal is 0

Tags: magento-2.1, zero-subtotal

I'm using `checkout_cart_product_add_after`observer.

In observer

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->save();

}
```

Above code is working properly for the first time.

I'm clearing cart everytime before any items are added to cart.

So that code is working properly in first time but if I add products to cart second time I'm getting subtotal of product 0.

I'm add multiple items into cart and it's working fine but I want to set custom price for each product that's why using above code...

Comment: Just try with remove  $item->save(); in your above code and check.

Comment: Just a guess... what if you add $item->getQuote()->collectTotals() after $item->save() ?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya : yes not working even without that.

Comment: please show full code for, How to get $price in your observer?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Consider it as static value for now

Comment: @RiccardoT : Sorry buddy, I'm learning Magento so didn't get you, I just want to add custom price to product for checkout process only so first everything is working fine but second time subtotal get empty....